# how update in sql in a join and order by

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

mi consult it's:

```
update enfermedades
    join
pacientes ON pacientes.id = enfermedades.paciente_id
    join
consultas ON consultas.paciente_id = pacientes.id
    join
signos_sintomas ON signos_sintomas.consulta_id = consultas.id 

set 
    enfermedades.diabetes = 1,
    bmi = signos_sintomas.imc_kg_m2,
    promedio_presion_sistolica = ((pa_de_pie_izquierda + pa_sentado_izquierda) / 2),
    microalbuminuria = 0,
    macroalbuminuria = 0,
    fibrilacion = 0,
    ecv = 0,
    duracion = 15,
    antiht = 0,
    diabetes = 0
where
    enfermedades.riesgo_diabetes_mellitus = 0
        and pacientes.situacion = 0
        and riesgo_diabetes_dano_organo_blanco = 0
        and signos_sintomas.created in (select 
            signos_sintomas.created,consultas.created
        from
            signos_sintomas
                join
            consultas ON consultas.id = signos_sintomas.consulta_id
                join
            pacientes ON pacientes.id = consultas.paciente_id
        where
            pacientes.id = pacientes.id
        order by signos_sintomas.created , consultas.created desc);
```

say

ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

as consulting but with that descending order for columns created

Answer (score 1):

You're using a sub-select in an `IN` clause that's returning multiple columns. Such a subselect can return only **ONE** column, which is used for the `IN()` comparison:

```
and signos_sintomas.created in (select 
            signos_sintomas.created,consultas.created
                    ^^^--field #1       ^---field #2
        from
```

if you return multiple columns, the DB server has no way of knowing WHICH column should be used for the `IN()` comparison.

Comment: thank but i need update. and say: Rows matched: 960  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

Comment: then you'll have to rebuild your query. generally speaking, most subselects can be written as normal join+where queries, which would allow you to use as many fields from the subqueried table(s) as you need.

Comment: because is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326902/sql-how-query-in-sql-order-by-created-in-this-case  need here

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
   and signos_sintomas.created in (select 
        signos_sintomas.created,consultas.created
```

to

```
   and signos_sintomas.created in (select 
        signos_sintomas.created
```

yould select just one column , not two .